# How do I convert strings into lowercase strings?

Tags: google-apps-script

I think im doing this wrong but this is what I did, and further up the code there's a line like getParagraphs().getText()[1] or something similar

```
 var nline2 = "Unknown Address, Please Input Manually"



  if (line2.substring().toLowerCase() === "msa"|| "math and science academy") {
    nline2 = "8430 Woodbury Crossing, Woodbury, MN 55125"
  }


  else if (line2.substring().toLowerCase() === "erhs"|| "east ridge high school" ) {
    nline2 = "4200 Pioneer Dr, Woodbury, MN 55129"
  }


  else if (line2.substring().toLowerCase() === "nb"|| "north branch") {
    nline2 = "38175 Grand Ave, North Branch, MN 55056"
  }


  else if (line2.substring().toLowerCase() === "pl" || "prior lake") {
    nline2 = "7575 150th St W, Savage, MN 55378"
  }

  else if (line2.substring().toLowerCase() === "lb"|| "library") {
    nline2 = "8595 Central Park Pl, Woodbury, MN 55125"
  }
  else {
   nline2 = "Unknown Command, Input address manually"
  }
```

There's also an appendParagraph(nline2) down the line but what keeps happening is that it keeps 
displaying the address for the msa, If i comment that out it keeps displaying the address for erhs, no matter what i put, even if its just an empty blank space. This repeats until everything is commented out except for the library and it just does the library

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with the substrings?

Comment: substring() method of the String.prototype accepts character indices as parameters. It then returns the part of the string between them. Are you trying to extract a part of the string?  Also, to make the code more readable, consider using switch-case instead of multiple ifs [More on switch case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

This also minimizes the number of function calls

```
var s=line2.toLowerCase();
  if (s=="msa"|| s=="math and science academy") {
    nline2 = "8430 Woodbury Crossing, Woodbury, MN 55125"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand you are trying to do, it's to change the value of your `nline2` depending in a value previously input, if that the case this code will help you:

```
function functionTest() {
  var nline2 = "text you want to insert";

  switch(nline2.toLowerCase()){

    case "msa" || "math and science academy":
      nline2 = "8430 Woodbury Crossing, Woodbury, MN 55125";
      break;

    case "erhs"|| "east ridge high school":
      nline2 = "4200 Pioneer Dr, Woodbury, MN 55129";
      break;

    case "nb"|| "north branch":
      nline2 = "38175 Grand Ave, North Branch, MN 55056";
      break;

    case "pl" || "prior lake":
      nline2 = "7575 150th St W, Savage, MN 55378";
      break;

    case "lb"|| "library":
      nline2 = "8595 Central Park Pl, Woodbury, MN 55125";
      break;

    default:
      nline2 = "Unknown Command, Input address manually";
  }

  Logger.log(nline2);
}
```

In this situation, using a [switch case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is a cleaner way to write your code. Also, you were having issues converting your strings into lowercases, on [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), you can check more about the [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method and the [String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) in general.